# How to find a element in selenium based on text from sibling?

Tags: html, selenium, screen-scraping

I've got a question concerning scraper selenium.

I've got a bunch of html, but every class has the same name. The only thing that distinguishes one class from the other is the textual value (marked in red). I want to get the element "Show More" for each of these classes. So I thought, to get this element, I'd somehow have to access it through the textual value in the span class _3QYUVo0T.

Anybody has any idea to go about this challenge? I already tried some things with follow-siblings but couldnt quite figure it out. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to reach to show more from **Cuisine** :

```
//span[text()='Cuisine']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::span[text()='Show more']
```

for **Dishes** :

```
 //span[text()='Dishes']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::span[text()='Show more']
```

### Code 1 :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Cuisine']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::span[text()='Show more']").click()
```

### Code 2 :

**With Explicit waits**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Cuisine']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::span[text()='Show more']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

if the above two do not work, try with JS :

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Cuisine']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::span[text()='Show more']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Answer (score 1):

To click `Show more` element below `Dishes` you can use this XPath:

```
//span[text()='Dishes']/../..//span[text()='Show more']
```

With Selenium `find_element` in Python it will be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Dishes']/../..//span[text()='Show more']").click()
```

You can use this in more smart and generic way passing the text as parameter.
Also you possibly will have to add a wait before clicking the element to make it loaded.